# Every 7th character of the line has to be a +

Tags: regex, bash, grep

The problem is the following:
I have a document called brain.txt with lines of characters like this:

```
++++++++++[>++++++++>++++++>+<<<-]>+++.>+++++.<-.+.>>. word
```

The `word` at the end can really be any word.
How can i filter the lines from the document where every 7th character is a plus?
example: `+......+......+......+..... word`

I wrote the following command:

```
egrep '^\+(.{6}\+)+.{,6}\s' brain.txt
```

But it does not seem to work, can anyone explain me what is incorrect about this command please?

Comment: The regex you've listed [will correctly capture](http://rubular.com/r/pxBsVORD2G) the input line you've given. What is the problem?

Comment: This question no longer makes sense because what was wrong with it was *fixed* in an edit..

Comment: @antak no I didn't fix it. the backslashes were just not displayed due to a lack of code formatting. the problem is still there and a different one

Comment: @ean5533 It just does not return any of the lines listed in the file.

Comment: @ean5533 the problem is regex flavor specific, so unfortunately, your argument is invalid ;)

Comment: @m.buettner oic, I thought the answer you deleted was spot on, but didn't know it was just a thing with SO.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @antak, no I just fell victim to the same mistake ;). I first posted the answer, then reformatted the question, but did not see that the backslashes were actually there. but luckily the mistake could now be found anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the shorthand notation `{,6}` which does not seem to work with the given regex flavor. Simply write it out:

```
egrep '^\+(.{6}\+)+.{0,6}\s' brain.txt
```

Note that this requires **at least 2** `+`s. The single `\+` at the beginning, and another one in the subpattern (because it is repeated at least once). If `+.... word` would be a valid line for you, use:

```
egrep '^\+(.{6}\+)*.{0,6}\s' brain.txt
```

Comment: @user1790040 ah okay, couldn't have known that ;)